# Google Sheets vlookup to prioritize a column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Wonder if anyone can help.

On the attached on tab 2 I'm trying to do a vlookup to tab 1 to use column 1 'code' to bring back column 3 'email'. But if there is more than 1 match in column 1 for 'code', prioritize the row that has Level 1 in column 2 in tab 1. For example, there are two code 20, on tab 1 but the formula should bring back row 5 - test4@live.co.uk rather than row 2 - test1@live.co.uk as row 5 has Level 1 in column 2. If there is no duplicate code in column 1 just bring back the first result in column 1.

I've got a formula already in column 3 in tab 2 but it isn't working as it doesn't bring back anything if there isn't level 1 in column 2, see column 4. On tab 3, I've got an example of what the right result should be. This can be either a vlookup, a match & index or what ever works as long as its in google sheets.

Addition to the above, it needs to be an array based on something being in column 1 and have an iferror, just in case. Thanks.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iVz9BNzUwMu9Vf7CIqju0IEkna29Wb7sR9ps_MVeF80/edit#gid=1198958997)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(vlookup(A2:A,sort(LookTable!A:C,2,),3,)))
```

[image]

*the above code prioritizes Level 1 over blank level. Not sure if there's goin' to be 10s of levels and I have to choose say level 15 over level 8 or so; then use this alternate variant*

```
=index(ifna(vlookup(A2:A,sort(LookTable!A2:C,--ifna(regexextract(LookTable!B2:B,"\d+")),),3,)))
```

Comment: Thanks rockinfreakshow. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

`XLOOKUP()` should also work with `search_mode` last to first. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,LookTable!A:A,LookTable!C:C,"",,-1)
```

For dynamic spill array, use-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,LookTable!A:A,LookTable!C:C,"",,-1)))
```

[image]